# Office 365 list items created by asp.net form submit button

Tags: office-365, asp.net

I have a query regarding SharePoint Office 365.

1. I have a form of any technology like php, asp.net, python
2. Three fields are there Name, Lastname and display name and submit button.
3. I have office online 365 account in which I have created site and created one custom list with same fields Name,lastname and dsiplay name.

What I want is that when a user fills the form and click on submit button, data should be entered in custom list.

Input can be from any technology like php, asp.net.

How can I accomplish this in Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

you can do with the client context object in your .net application by adding reference of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime;

i have done with console application by following code

```
string login = "office 365 username";
        string password = "office 365 password";
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        //Authenticate to office 365
        var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("office 365 url"))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            // You can do operation with client context object

        }
```

Plz refer this link for insert, update, delete with client context object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539976.aspx

Hope it helps...

Comment: Please help with webservice, list.asmx because input can be from any technology also not decided machine should have sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can update list on sharepoint online using Client side object model.

```
using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
 clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
                SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
                ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);

                oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

                oListItem.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am updating the answer with some code sample. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please give me some useful links or code. It would be more helpful.

Comment: Are you sure this code will run in asp.net form, I mean client context.

Comment: Yes, it will. This is client object model. This will run from all machines from where sharepoint is accessible.

Comment: Please help with webservice, list.asmx becuase input can be from any technology also not decided machine should have sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to user2861804's answer, using [JSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx) instead of [CSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
function createListItem(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

`getByTitle()` uses the display name, not the internal name, and vice versa for `set_item()`.

Comment: Please help with webservice, list.asmx becuase input can be from any technology also not decided machine should have sharepoint

Comment: Just to clarify, the aspx file is not in SharePoint, but rather hosted elsewhere, which may or may not reside on the SharePoint server?

Comment: yes you are right, but above code will ask for sharepoint reference and not necessary it would be asp.net form it can be of php form too, python form too

Comment: Well, C# would be the approach to go with an asp.net form.  See answers from user2861804 and Hitesh for more information.  You'll have to include the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` files in your solution.  As for PHP, I've no experience with PHP, so I'm of no use to you.  As for the list.asmx, I have insufficient experience to be of real help.  Here's a link that may be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx.